# Show/hide jQuery menu click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have the following code for my menu, the trouble is I want it to hide/close as soon as I click on one of the options, instead of closing at the X button:

THIS IS THE HTML

MENU

```
<div class="mobilenav"> 
 <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">TALK</a></li> 
</div>
```

ICON

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon"> 
<div class="MENU"> 
 <div class="menui top-menu"></div> 
 <div class="menui mid-menu"></div> 
 <div class="menui bottom-menu"></div> 
</div> 
</a>
```

AND JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".icon").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
});
```

Comment: Can you post the html here?  Offhand, I suspect some of these classes are nested in such a fashion that there are conflicting calls.  Separately, the `fadeOut` may conflict with  `fadeToggle` if .dialog is a child of .mobilenav  Also, note you have two listeners for click.  Presumably a click on .icon is ALSO a click on document.  Check those 2 avenues first.  Would be helpful if you could post a jsfiddle, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( ".icon" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
});
```

This will bind the click function to the class. Also a side-note watch where you place your scripts. From personal experience I've had best results putting all js code (inline and external) right before the  tag (even when using document.ready()) but this is probably just personal preference.

[DOCUMENTATION FOR BIND](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: thanks but still nothing, the menu keeps open after i click one of the options

Comment: Try switching the ".icon" with "a". That might do the trick.  @GregoryLoginow

Comment: thanks men, you're a genius, worked perfectly changing it for an "a"

Comment: @GregoryLoginow No problem glad to help1

Comment: ok, i did change the ".icon" with "a", but now anytime i click on an <a> tag the menu opens...

Comment: @GregoryLoginow Give a class to your .a elements you need to close the menu then put that class name instead of .a in the function.